# GRAILSUI Datatable - saving and restoring state between invocations

Tags: grails, yui-datatable

I have a datatable thru which a user can page and select a record for display ..
The record replaces the the entire datatable with another one via an Ajax call
.. On the second

datatable is a button to allow you to return to the first .. Currently when you
do so you are returned to the start of the first table .. What i want to do is 
store the state of the first datatable (current page, offset, max records .. )
when a record is selected so i can restore it when they go back to it .. 
Actually storing the info is not so much of a problem - it's how to reapply it
so my first table is as the user left it  .??

I had a look around and found some code  ..

```
YAHOO.util.Event.onDOMReady(function(e) {

      var offset =  new YAHOO.util.Element('offset').get('value');
      var max =  new YAHOO.util.Element('max').get('value');

      var state = GRAILSUI.receiptBatchList.getState();
      state.sorting = state.sortedBy;
      state.pagination.recordOffset = offset;
      state.paginator.rowsPerPage = max;

      var query = GRAILSUI.receiptBatchList.buildQueryString(state);

      GRAILSUI.receiptBatchList.getDataSource().sendRequest(query,{
        success : GRAILSUI.receiptBatchList.onDataReturnReplaceRows,
        failure : GRAILSUI.receiptBatchList.onDataReturnReplaceRows,
        scope  : GRAILSUI.receiptBatchList,
        argument: state
      });
```

where offset and max are just hiden values on the page but i can't get this to work and i'd really hoped it would be reasonably quick
to implement  ..

Any suggestions  ?

TIA ..

Answer (score 0):

As a quick hack, you can save the params' part responsible for table state from a controller action on a server side, like:

```
def list = {

  Map savedState = userService.currentUser.tableStates['MyController']
  if (savedState) {
    params << savedState
  }

  // ... list instances

  Map tableState = params.subMap(['max', 'offset', 'sort', 'order']) // add your filtering param name if you do some filtering
  userService.currentUser.tableStates['MyController'] = tableState
  // ... return instances
}
```

`currentUser`, sure, has to be singleton or persistent.